# Laravel in shared hosting access denied for user 'Cpanel_username'@'Ip or name host server' (using password : yes)

Tags: database, laravel-4

I hosted my website (Laravel 4.2 application) in justhost.com, but I can not make a connection with the database, I get the following error: Access denied for user 'Cpanel_username' @ 'Ip or host name server' (using password: yes). knowing that I have checked the connection parameters several times.

Comment: Can you please provide your database.php snippet for the config in app/config?

Comment: i use .env.php like this :                                                                                              <?php

return array (
     'HOST' => 'just47.justhost.com',
     'DATABASE' => 'automarc_db',
     'USERNAME' => 'automarc_yaskab',
     'PASSWORD' => '***************************',
);

Comment: and database.php like this :                                                                                                'mysql' => array(
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => $_ENV['HOST'],
   'database'  => $_ENV['DATABASE'],
   'username'  => $_ENV['USERNAME'],
   'password'  => $_ENV['PASSWORD'],
   'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
   'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
   'prefix'    => '',
  ),

Comment: Thanks guys, it works the probelm you should use localhost in host name because i'm not connecting remotely from inside the server.